# Компиляция gdb 7.12 из исходников Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Не пойму проблему и как её решить.
[Скачал](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/) gdb-7.12.tar.gz
разархивировал в папку /media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Program/gdb-7.12

```
cd /media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Program/gdb-7.12    
./configure
make
sudo make install | grep шибка
/media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Program/gdb-7.12/missing: 81: /media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Program/gdb-7.12/missing: makeinfo: not found
WARNING: 'makeinfo' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified a '.texi' file, or
         any other file indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual.
         You might want to install the Texinfo package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/>
         The spurious makeinfo call might also be the consequence of
         using a buggy 'make' (AIX, DU, IRIX), in which case you might
         want to install GNU make:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/make/>
make[5]: *** [gdb.info] Ошибка 127
Makefile:503: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «gdb.info»
make[4]: *** [subdir_do] Ошибка 1
Makefile:1519: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «subdir_do»
make[3]: *** [install-only] Ошибка 2
Makefile:1253: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «install-only»
make[2]: *** [install] Ошибка 2
Makefile:1250: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «install»
make[1]: *** [install-gdb] Ошибка 2
Makefile:9190: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «install-gdb»
make: *** [install] Ошибка 2
Makefile:2253: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «install»
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install texinfo попробуйте перед этим

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов спасибо, помогло. оформите в виде ответа, если можно с пояснением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сообщение `'makeinfo' is missing on your system` намекает, что соответствующей программы нет на машине. Беглое гугление показывает, что makeinfo в Ubuntu находится в пакете texinfo. Соответственно, решение такое:

```
sudo apt-get install texinfo
```